Grub login doesnt allow backspace
I put a username and password in the Grub menu. When I type my username incorrectly, I cannot delete the wrong letter. The Backspace key writes a space character instead of deleting.
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-45-generic (64-bit)
ASUS PRIME B450M-K II
My grub.cfg  : https://shrib.com/#Vienna_1aAML0

Are you using a default US English keyboard layout for GRUB, or are you using some other layout? What does grep keymap /boot/grub.cfg return?

Hi. grub.cfg doesnt have keyboard configuration line

Does Ctrl-u (undo) works, to wipe out the whole password you have typed? If it does, it's a workaround a bit strong, but a workaround however.

Hi Marc,it not working.

After logging in successfully, if you type a backspace in your Desktop's terminal do you see the same character as you do in Grub?

Hi eyoung100 , desktops terminal works flawlessly, no problems whatsoever.

How does Ctrl+H work in the same situation? (It's the Backspace control character). Also Try Ctrl+V then the backspace key. Does it print anything specific?

Hi SmallClanger, These combinations do not write or delete any characters.

Try Ctrl+Alt+Supr to "reload" GRUB. Probably the solution lies using grub-mklayout, but it's a rabbit hole...
